# Laser communication system to transmit Audio

Tags: audio, communication, laser-diode, optical-fibre, optical

The audio in these two circuits is only transmitted when they are both connected to the same battery (Vcc), and only the laser control audio level not the transmitting process.

When I connect the receiver to a different battery the audio is not transmitted.

What could be wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: A capacitor at input Vin should be used.

Comment: Unless you're using this in the dark, your photo-resistor is probably being swamped by ambient light.

Comment: What does this mean --> *and only the laser control audio level not the transmitting process*

Comment: Also, a capacitor before R8 should help clipping. You have the potential of ambient light creating a large voltage offset on the op-amp.

Comment: how many Pico/nano Farads should the capacitor be? any range suggestions.